# Is VB/ASP having full support in Windows 2008 R2 X64 OS?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I have ASP sites using VB components for printing and writing logs, in our production environment. I need to migrate all these apps to 2008 R2 X64.

Can someone please let me know if VB/ASP is supported on this new OS? Please point me to the links where we have similar discussions.

Thanks in advance, 
RCM

Answer (score 0):

All those tools are available on 64-bit.  Keep in mind you will need to install everything intentionally.  Nothing will be there by default.